# Pure CSS Dropdown Menu Without Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried and end up with the following snippet.

The only thing remaining is, I have to click somewhere else to close the dropdown.

Expected: The dropdown should be closed when I choose the item.

I want it:

1. Pure CSS
2. Without Modifying given HTML
3. Without Adding JavaScript

   ```js
   function toggleClasses(e) {
     document.querySelector('.selected').className = '';
     e.target.className = 'selected';
   }
   ```

   ```css
   button {
     width: 100%;
     height: 40px;
   }

   .selected {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
   }

   button:not(.selected) {
     display: none;
   }

   .dropdown:focus-within button {
     display: block;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="dropdown">
     <button onClick="toggleClasses(event);" class="selected">link 1</button>
     <button onClick="toggleClasses(event);">link 2</button>
     <button onClick="toggleClasses(event);">link 3</button>
     <button onClick="toggleClasses(event);">link 4</button>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Have you [searched](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=pure+css+dropdown&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix2J7tqabeAhUMMo8KHciZDscQ1QIIdCgD)? What have you tried? If you don't want script, whey the js tag? `document.querySelector('.selected').className = '';` might be better as `document.querySelector('.selected').classList.remove('selected');`

Comment: I'm confused, there's Javascript in your example, yet you're asking not to use it ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak I don't want to ad more scripts and would like to achieve with Pure CSS. The attached JS is just to add / remove class.

Comment: adding a simple checkbox to the top, will solve it.

Comment: It can be achieved with many other ways if I can modify HTML / JS but the challenge is to change without modifying HTML / JS. I'm still trying to achieve this.

Comment: `I have to click somewhere else to close the dropdown` other than clicking somewhere else, how do you want that to happen ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak it should be closed when I choose any item.

Comment: @w3debugger I found a way but you should do double click on the same value instead of just one

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because when you click on another button, there is still focus within the dropdown.